# Easiest way to make numbered images disappear after clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some pretty basic code with images of the numbers 1-10 (titled 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.) on the screen. A random number is generated and if the image of the correct number is clicked, a prompt is displayed. If the incorrect number is clicked, I'd like for the image to disappear. I know how to make this happen with separate functions for each image but what's the best way to do this all in one function?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Use addEventListener on the parent element and check the event.target

Answer (score 0):

In the first place: some snippets of your code would be helpful for giving a qualified answer here.

Assuming something like this is your actual html structure (note: you could leave out some steps, if you would have an `id` in your `img` tags, like `<img src="1.jpg" id="1">`):

```html
<div id="image-wrapper">
   <img src="1.jpg">
   <img src="2.jpg">
   <img src="3.jpg">
   ...
</div>
```

Using plain JavaScript you could do something like this:

```js
var rnd = ... //produce your random number
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => {
   img.onclick = () => {
      let src = img.src;
      src = src.split("/"); //get an array of the source of your image
      src = src[src.length - 1]; //get the last position inside the array (resembling the filename)
      src = src.split("."); //split the filename by '.' (to separate filename and -type in the next step)
      src = src[0];
      src = parseInt(src); //make the extracted src and the random number you produced comparable by converting to int
      if(rnd !== src) {
         img.parentElement.removeChild(img);
      } else {
         alert("foo"); //your prompt
      }
   };
});
```

Explanation: Using the method `document.querySelectorAll` you can select an array of html nodes (with the same selectors you may be used to from CSS). You can iterate over this array now by using `array.forEach` (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for further explanation). On each `img` you can now register an `onclick`-method. Given that you really just have `src` of the `img` as a discriminator you have to extract the actual filename from the src in the next step.

After comparing your random number to the filename you make use of the fact, that you are working on an actual DOM-Object here (in the forEach-loop): you get the parent node by `Node.parentElement` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)) where you can give the command to remove one of its' children (which is -in our case- our current image).

I hope that helped you - for more help, please provide some more information on the question :)